# Using command line parameters outside of main function

Tags: c++, command-line, program-entry-point, argv, file-import

I would like a program to read in a file entered by the user via the command line, which is then used in the main body of the code.

See example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct run_t {
    std::string file;
};

run_t run;

const POINTER* ptr = toy(run.file, 0);

// Here hardcoded the FILENAME as a string => code works.
// I am trying to get it to work when I read in the filename from the
// first entry on the command line upon program execution:
//
//const POINTER* ptr = toy("FILENAME", 0);

double Toy1(double a, double b, double c) {
    return ptr->func(a, b, c);
};

double Toy2(double d) {
    double factor = pow(d, 2); //some dummy prefactor
    return factor * Toy1(4, 5, 6);
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    run_t run;
    run.file = argv[1];
    std::cout << Toy2(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The actual `toy` and `Toy` functions are software-specific and recognised by additional include-files. If I manually hardcode `run.file` in `toy(run.file, 0)` with the string `FILENAME`, compile and execute with a single command line parameter (`./exe 1`, say) then the program works.

My question is, how to modify the above code so that the value `FILENAME` entered in the command line is read in instead as `run.file`? That is, to make `./exe FILENAME` work? I have tried with declaring `argv[1]` as the argument of toy but I have not yet got this to work.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of all the attempts you mention. I want to see how you used the c-style string pointer `argv[1]` as parameter in `toy()` and which type you declared for that parameter. Within `main()` you seem to be aware that it is a `char *` and not a C++ string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I have tested. Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

struct run_t {
    std::string file;
};

run_t run;

class POINTER{
  public:
    POINTER(std::string file , int num){std::cout << "POINTER::POINTER(std::string file , int num)file " << file << std::endl;};
    double func(double a, double b, double c) {
        POINTER *toy(std::string file , int num);
        return (double)0;
    }
};


POINTER *toy(std::string file , int num)
{
    POINTER* ptr = new POINTER(file , num);
    std::cout << "POINTER *toy(std::string file , int num) file " << file << std::endl;
    return ptr;
}

const POINTER * ptr;

double Toy1(double a, double b, double c) {
    POINTER * ptrCst = const_cast<POINTER *>(ptr);
    return ptrCst->func(a, b, c);
};

double Toy2(double d) {
    double factor = pow(d, 2); //some dummy prefactor
    return factor * Toy1(4, 5, 6);
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    run.file = argv[1];
    POINTER * ptrCst = const_cast<POINTER *>(ptr);
    ptrCst = toy(run.file, 0);
    std::cout << Toy2(1) << std::endl;
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove const from the type pointed to by `ptr`? You've probably added a `const_cast` without a good reason here. Also C++ style casts imho are always preferrable to C style casts and for cast types like const casts it's better to add a comment about why you don't get into undefined behaviour by using this cast...

Comment: @8-DK thanks for your answer! Yes this works for me (the first version of your answer worked for me too).

Answer (score 1):

First, `ptr` is initialised too early, at a time where `argv[1]` is not available.

Second, `main` local variable `run` is not related to global `run` used to set `ptr` that is used in `Toy1`.

As we don't know what `toy` is we can not answer much more. **8-DK** answer's is one possibility.

Comment: The pointer is non-const; it's the value pointed to that is const. You can reassign `const AnyType *` which may be an error on the OPs part... `const POINTER* const ptr = ...;` would a declaration causing issues when trying to reassign `ptr`.

Comment: @fabian Right, misread the code.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks for the explanation!